# Dynamically load components without breaking AoT - Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

So I was trying to create a module which would take a bunch of components and load them dynamically but without messing with AoT. This has proven a challenge but I'm getting really close except for one thing. How do I retrieve all the components which are stored in the ComponentFactory?

In mij `app.module.ts` I pass an array of components to the forRoot() of my dynamic-load module:

```
imports: [
  DynamicLoadModule.forRoot(dynamicComponents),
]
```

In my `dynamic-load.module.ts` I add all of them to the Angular2 ComponentFactory:

```
static forRoot(components: any[]) {
        return {
            ngModule: DynamicLoadModule,
            providers: [{
                provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
                useValue: components,
                multi: true,
            }, {
                provide: DynamicLoadService,
                useValue: new DynamicLoadService(components)
            }]
        };
    }
```

Now the problem lies in the `DynamicLoadService`, which is messing with AoT. I've tried the documented export-a-function way but this doesn't solve the problem because this way I'm unable to pass the `components` as parameters to the service. So the following found in [the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) is not providing a solution for my problem:

```
let heroServiceFactory = (logger: Logger, userService: UserService) => {
  return new HeroService(logger, userService.user.isAuthorized);
};

export let heroServiceProvider =
  { provide: HeroService,
    useFactory: heroServiceFactory,
    deps: [Logger, UserService]
  };
```

So then I tried passing the components to my `dynamic-load.module` by the use of `OpaqueToken`, which was also of no help because I then had uncompiled components at best and my module lost a lot of flexibilty.

So I came to the conclusion that, if I needed an array of all the components in the `ComponentFactory`, I just need a way to retrieve them all.
So, where I now use the `ComponentFactoryResolver` to get one template based on the name I need to get them all, or at least get all the names of the components in the factory.

```
if (selectedComponent !== '') {
  if (typeof this.currentComponent !== 'undefined') { this.currentComponent.destroy(); }

  const   components = this.dynamicLoadService.getComponents(), // --> instead of getting a list of available components through this service which needs the factory that blocks AoT, I should just be able to retrieve all available components from the ComponentFactory
          component: any = components.find((x) => x.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(selectedComponent) > -1),
          compFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(component);

  this.currentComponent = this.vcr.createComponent(compFactory);
  this.currentComponent.instance.data = this.componentData;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**
So the first answer did not quite solve the problem but another helpful person was able to help me fix the problem through the [Angular Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14758).

In the end my code looks as follows:

```
import { NgModule, ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicLoadService } from './dynamic-load.service';

import { DynamicLoadComponent } from './dynamic-load.component';

export function DynamicLoadFactory(cmps) {
    return new DynamicLoadService(cmps);
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        DynamicLoadComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        DynamicLoadComponent
    ]
})
export class DynamicLoadModule {
    static forRoot(components: any[]) {
        return {
            ngModule: DynamicLoadModule,
            providers: [{
                provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
                useValue: components,
                multi: true
            },
            {
                provide: 'ENTRIES',
                useValue: components
            },
            {
                provide: DynamicLoadService,
                useFactory: DynamicLoadFactory,
                deps: [[new Inject('ENTRIES')]]
            }]
        };
    }
}
```

As was pointed out to me `ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS` is not part of dependency injection tree (Find the source [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L805-L809)). So the above workaround deals with that problem.

---

So the answer was presented to me be a very helpful person at the Angular Github.

It was suggested to me that I should just

> Just inject `ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS` into `DynamicLoadService`

Which now looks like this:

```
export function DynamicLoadFactory(cmps) {
  return new DynamicLoadService(cmps);
}

export class DynamicLoadModule {
    static forRoot(components: any[]) {
        return {
            ngModule: DynamicLoadModule,
            providers: [{
                provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
                useValue: components,
                multi: true,
            }, {
                provide: DynamicLoadService,
                useFactory: DynamicLoadFactory,
                deps: [new Inject(ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS)]
            }]
        };
    }
}
```

[source at Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14758)